# Получить данные с VIEW1, обработать и передать, открыть VIEW2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет!
Помогите разобраться!
Есть VIEW1, в которой нужно считать переменные  id_user,FirstName,LastName.
На форме есть несколько кнопок:"Сохранить","Удалить","Открыть"
Есть VIEW2, которое открывается по кнопке "открыть" и туда переносятся значения переменных id_user,FirstName,LastName.

Как это реализовать на MVC 5?

Answer (score 0):

AccountCotroller.cs

```
    [Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

{...

```
    public void ActivationPlan(int id_instance, int id_plane, String id_user)
    {
       .....
        List<PaymentDataPOST> MyPaymentDataPOST = new List<PaymentDataPOST>();

        MyPaymentDataPOST.Add(P);
        ViewBag.PaymentDataPOST = MyPaymentDataPOST;
     }



    public ActionResult ClickDetails(String slctplane, String Description,String SaveInstance, string AddInstance, string ActivePlane, string RestartInstance, string GeneratePassword, string ResetDB, String DelInstance)
    {
        String UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // Получили ID пользователя




        ......




        if (ActivePlane != null)
        {

            // Активация
            ActivationPlan(Convert.ToInt32(SaveInstance), Convert.ToInt32(slctplane), UserID);
                Redirect("/Account/PayModulbankPOST");

 }
```

}

Details.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Подробнее/";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>




<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ClickDetails", "Account", FormMethod.Post))

{




    <div>


        <h2>Подробнее</h2>

        <div class="cloud-box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Информация о инстанции</h3>

                </div>

            </div>



  @foreach (var i in ViewBag.Details)

  { 
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <table class="table cloud-data">
                        <tbody>


                            <tr>
                                <td>Название</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="Description" type="text" value="@i.Description" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">



                                    <button name="SaveInstance" value="@i.key_Instance" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></i>
                                        Сохранить
                                    </button>



                                    <button name="DelInstance" value="@i.key_Instance" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></i>
                                        Удалить
                                    </button>



                               </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
    <td>Тарифный план</td>

    <td>

        <select name="slctplane" id="1">

            @foreach       (var tp in ViewBag.Planes)
   {

        if (i.ID_plane!=tp.key_plane)
        {
       <option value="@tp.key_plane"> @tp.Name_plane @tp.Price_usd $ в месяц </option>
        }

   } 

            <option  selected value="@i.ID_plane" > @i.Name_plane @i.Price_usd $ в месяц </option>/option>

        </select>



                                    <button type="button" value="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ActivePlaneDlg">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>
                                        Активировать
                                    </button>




                                    <div class="modal fade" id="ActivePlaneDlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ActivePlaneTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ActivePlaneTitle">Активация тарифного плана</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    Старый тарифный план будет аннулирован.
                                                    Активировать и оплатить новый тарифный план?
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">

                                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="ActivePlane" name="ActivePlane" value="id_plane=1">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>
                                                        Да
                                                    </button>

                                                    <!--
                                                                                                        <input type="submit" name="ActivePlane" value="Сохранить" />
                                                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Да</button> -->
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Нет</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>




                                </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Статус тарифного плана</td>
                                <td>
                                    <font color="green">Активирован</font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Дата продления</td>
                                <td>01.01.2019</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Автопродление</td>
                                <td>Активировано</td>
                            </tr>



                            <tr>
                                <td>Сервер</td>
                                <td>@i.Name_domain</td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td>Пользователь</td>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Login_inst


                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-cloud btn-cloud-danger btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RebootInstanceDlg">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                                        Перезапуск
                                    </button>






                                    <div class="modal fade" id="RebootInstanceDlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="RebootInstanceTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="RebootInstanceTitle">Перезагрузка</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    Вы уверены, что хотите перезагрузить инстанс?
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                   <!-- <button type="button" name="RestartInstance" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Да</button>

                                                    <input type="submit" name="RestartInstance" value="Да" />-->


                                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="RestartInstance" name="RestartInstance" value="id_instance=1">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                                                        Да
                                                    </button>     

                                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Нет</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Пароль
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @i.Password_inst



                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-cloud btn-cloud-danger btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ResetPasswordInstanceDlg">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                                        Сгенерировать
                                    </button>


                                    <div class="modal fade" id="ResetPasswordInstanceDlg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ResetPasswordInstanceTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ResetPasswordInstanceTitle">Генерация нового пароля</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    Сгенерировать новый пароль?
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">


                                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="GeneratePassword" name="GeneratePassword" value="id_plane=2">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                                                        Да
                                                    </button>                                                    

                                                   <!-- <button type="button" id="GeneratePassword" class="btn btn-secondary" value="id_psw=1" name="GeneratePassword" data-dismiss="modal">Да</button>  -->


                                                    <!--<input type="submit" name="GeneratePassword" value="Да" />-->

<!--
                                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="resetdb" name="ResetDB" value="id_plane=1">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                                        Сброс БД
                                                    </button>
                                                    >-->
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Нет</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>




                                </td>
                            </tr>

<!----------------------------Начало: Список доступных портов---------------------------------------------------->


                            @foreach (var a in ViewBag.PortsDetail)

                            { 





                            <tr>

                                <td>Протокол</td>
                                <td>
                                   @a.NamePort
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td>Порт №</td>
                                <td>
                                    @a.NumPort
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <hr>

                            }
<!---------------------------Конец: Список доступных портов------------------------------------------------------>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Сброс БД</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    Это сотрет все сохраненные сообщения в БД.
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <form action="https://api.gerfed.ru/console/9751325/details/reset" class="pull-right" id="reset-form" method="post">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="resetdb" name="ResetDB" value="id_plane=1">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                            Сброс БД
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>API</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <strong>API ключ</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <code></code>
                </div>
            </div>

      }  
        </div>
   </div> 

}

</body>
</html>
```

PayModulbankPOST.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Оплата.";
}
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <title>PayModulbank</title>


</head>
<body>





        <form method="post" action="https://pay.modulbank.ru/pay">



            <input name="testing" , value="ViewBag.PaymentDataPOST.testing">
            <input name="unix_timestamp" , value="ViewBag.PaymentDataPOST.unix_timestamp" />
            <input type="hidden" name="salt" , value="ViewBag.PaymentDataPOST..salt">
            <input type="hidden" name="order_id" , value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" , value="111">
            <input type="hidden" name="merchant" , value="ViewBag.PaymentDataPOST..merchant">
            <input type="hidden" name="signature" , value="ViewBag.PaymentDataPOST.signature">
            <input type="hidden" name="description" , value="Платеж №1.">
            <input name="client_phone" , value="+7 912 9876543">
            <input name="client_email" , value="test@test.ru">
            <input type="hidden" name="success_url" , value="http://myawesomesite.com/payment_success">
            <input type="hidden" name="fail_url" , value="http://myawesomesite.com/payment_fail">
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить платеж">

        </form>


</body>
</html>
```